# Why isn't my navbar appearing on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering if anyone can help solve this problem it would be much appreciated. Why isn't my navbar appearing on my [website](https://liamdocherty.github.io)? I have reviewed my HTML, CSS AND JS and can't seem to identify the problem. Here is my GitHub website [link.](https://github.com/liamdocherty/liamdocherty.github.io) I do believe the problem could be with the JS though.

JS

```
var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]');

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
        const features_top = $(".features-icons").position().top;
        const top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (top_of_window >= features_top) {
            $('.navbar').css('display', 'flex') // display: flex
        } else {
            $(".navbar").hide();
        }
    });
}); // This is just a sample script. Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.

if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
    of_beautifier();
} else {
    var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
}
```

Comment: I can't really look at the site, at the moment, but could you just use the CSS `position: fixed` for the navbar?

Comment: The navigation bar is meant to appear when the user scrolls down to the features-icons section. Not right at the top of the website on the homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add reference of `smooth-scroll.js` file before `javascript.js` file because of `javascript.js` code use `smooth-scroll.js` object.

```
<script src="js/smooth-scroll-master/dist/js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>

<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

It will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you javascript.js uses smooth scroll so it should be included first.

else

you can include or use it in javascript.js like this

```
$.getScript("js/smooth-scroll-master/dist/js/smooth-scroll.js", function() {
var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]');

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
        const features_top = $(".features-icons").position().top;
        const top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (top_of_window >= features_top) {
            $('.navbar').css('display', 'flex') // display: flex
        } else {
            $(".navbar").hide();
        }
    });
}); // This is just a sample script. Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.

if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
    of_beautifier();
} else {
    var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
}
});
```